# How to see all of scripts on Chrome's dev tool?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Hello. I'm fixing some scripts from website which made by other one.

First I should look all of existing scripts but chrome dev tool doesn't show all of the source code in script tag.

I tried to copy it but still copied with "...".

I searched some keyword from the whole webpage code and I can find it in hidden part so maybe Chrome get a full script but just not showing to me.

How can I see all of scripts?

Comment: Go to the "Sources" tab, not the DOM inspector one.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the *ellipsis* or single click on the arrow to expand the script region:

[image]

You could also try right click and copy the outer HTML or you can edit the node as HTML inline... Explore the other options available to you in the context menu:

[image]

> **NOTE:** If you are editing an existing web page you should probably start with the source code for the site and use an HTML code editor to edit the page and scripts, otherwise any changes you make wont be *fixing* the site for all users, the changes will be just for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. However I mean about "...", not a arrow. Finally I found the way to get full code. I can get it by "Ctrl U".

Comment: View-Source will certainly work for the entire page